# Remove Duplicate Numbers Status exist?

Tags: mysql, database

How to remove the duplicate into a new table?

For example in the table:

```
id |   number      |    status    | statusdate 
1  | 12121312      |   Processing | 01/06/2015  12:32:00
2  | 12121312      |   Processing | 02/06/2015  13:37:00
3  | 12121312      |   Processing | 03/06/2015  14:29:00
4  | 99999999      |   Processing | 03/06/2015  15:33:00
5  | 99999999      |   Completed  | 03/06/2015  18:39:00
6  | 99999999      |   Completed  | 04/06/2015  19:39:00
```

1. From `id` 1 to 3 there are duplicate number but there is NO "Completed" status, so get the number from the oldest date
2. From `id` 4 to 6, there are duplicate number but "Completed" status does exist. Get the the number from the newest date

In a new table, it should be like this:

```
id |   number      |    status    | statusdate 
1  | 12121312      |   Processing | 01/06/2015  12:32:00
6  | 99999999      |   Completed  | 04/06/2015  19:39:00
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Are `Completed`and `Processing` only possible statuses?

Comment: Would just *selecting* these work? Not deleting them could help you keep a log.

Comment: @JohnBupit Yes, just selecting would work should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an unoptimized version:

```
DELETE FROM table_name as T
WHERE ( 
        number in (SELECT number
                   FROM table_name
                   WHERE status = 'Completed')
        AND statusdate < (SELECT MAX(statusdate)
                          FROM table_name
                          GROUP BY number
                          HAVING number = T.number)
    )
    OR
    (
        number in (SELECT number
                   FROM table_name
                   WHERE status = 'Processing')
        AND statusdate > (SELECT MIN(statusdate)
                          FROM table_name
                          GROUP BY number
                          HAVING number = T.number)                   
    );
```

These are the records it deletes:

```
id  number      status      statusdate
2   12121312    Processing  February, 06 2015 13:37:00
3   12121312    Processing  March, 06 2015 14:29:00
4   99999999    Processing  March, 06 2015 15:33:00
5   99999999    Completed   March, 06 2015 18:39:00
6   99999999    Completed   April, 06 2015 19:39:00
```

Just replace `SELECT * FROM` to `DELETE FROM` in the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0192/2).

Answer (score 2):

For selecting records without duplicates:

```
select t1.* 
from tableName t1 JOIN
     tablename t2 on t1.number=t2.number 
                 and t1.status>=t2.status 
                 and t1.statusdate>t2.statusdate
group by t1.status
order by id
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae2fd/20)

For removing duplicates from the table:

```
delete from tableName
where id NOT IN 
    (select t1.id 
    from tableName t1 JOIN
         tablename t2 on t1.number=t2.number 
                     and t1.status>=t2.status 
                     and t1.statusdate>t2.statusdate
    group by t1.status) as Tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that items are added to database in chronological order, this will provide you a list of IDs you need:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(IF(status='Completed',id,NULL)),MIN(IF(status='Processing',id,NULL))) 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY number;
```

You can then select those rows:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
 WHERE id IN (select coalesce(max(if(status='Completed',id,null)),min(if(status='Processing',id,null))) 
from yourtable
group by number);
```

Or delete others, if that's needed.